# Oracle INSERT ALL WHEN conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

Using Oracle 11g RAC

I would like to use INSERT ALL to insert into one or two tables depending on a condition.  I'm trying to do this in regular SQL instead of a procedure if possible.  I read the WHEN condition needs to be satisfied by a variable in the SELECT part but Im not sure if there is some Oracle trick to return what I need.  Here is what I want to do:

```
INSERT ALL
  --if the order from table A doesnt exist in table B then insert it
  WHEN ( if a.ord_id = b.ord_id then skip) THEN
    INTO tableB (ord_id, ord_dt, ord_type, ord_sys) VALUES (ord_id,ord_dt, ord_type,ord_sys)
  --always insert into table C
  WHEN 1=1 THEN
   INTO tableC (ord_id, item_id, item_dt) VALUES (ord_id, 1234, SYSDATE)
  SELECT a.ord_id, a.ord_dt, a.ord_type, a.ord_sys
  FROM tableA a, tableB b
  WHERE a.ord_id = b.ord_id
  AND ord_type = 'N';
```

I tried several different things but cant seem to get the condition to really work.  I think the logic above wont work because it completely eliminates the selection but I thought it would be easier to understand. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is your first WHEN; `WHEN ( if a.ord_id = b.ord_id then skip) THEN` the [*conditional insert clause*](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9014.htm#i2079970) (as it's apparently known) actually looks like this (simplified for ease of reading)

```
[ ALL | FIRST ]
WHEN condition
THEN insert_into_clause
  [ values_clause ]
  [ insert_into_clause [ values_clause ] ]...
[ WHEN condition
  THEN insert_into_clause
    [ values_clause ]
]...
[ ELSE insert_into_clause
  [ values_clause ]
]
```

As you can see the WHEN just requires a condition, that is a Boolean statement such as `a.ord_id = b.ord_id`. You cannot use IF statements or other keywords such as SKIP.

Your comment in the code is *"if the order from table A doesnt exist in table B then insert it"*. If you perform an outer join between `tablea` and `tableb` then the non-existence in b is defined by the order being NULL (see [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)). You can use this fact to create your condition

```
insert all
 when b.ord_id is null then
   into tableb (ord_id, ord_dt, ord_type, ord_sys) 
   values (ord_id, ord_dt, ord_type, ord_sys)
 when 1 = 1 then
   into tablec (ord_id, item_id, item_dt) 
   values (ord_id, 1234, sysdate)
select a.ord_id, a.ord_dt, a.ord_type, a.ord_sys
  from tablea a
  left outer join tableb b
    on a.ord_id = b.ord_id
 where a.ord_type = 'N';
```

If `ORD_TYPE` is actually in `tableb` you'll have to remove the WHERE clause and add this condition to the JOIN instead.

Comment: Ben, thank you very much.  I tried something similar previously and it didnt work.  You confirmed it could be done and now I see my error was because I was trying to use the table alias (actually how you have it) but its not supported so I abandoned the idea.  After going through your sql and rereading multi_table_insert I see that I should have tried a column alias.  Your above insert should be corrected to say "when tableb_ord_id is null then"  and the select should contain a "b.ord-id tableb_ord_id".  This works great...thanks again for the help.